# Javascript with cron

Tags: javascript, php, cron

I am using codeigniter and cpanel for database. I have set one cronjob. In cronjob function I am calling one function. In that function I am creating one pdf - it includes maps and charts. And I created link for cron. When I am clicking that link in browser, it is working. But in cronjob it is not working.

```php
public function distance_report_test_pdf($test)
{
    $this->load->view('client_admin/distance_reporttest',$data);
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  get_pdfreport();
}

function get_pdfreport()
{
  window.location.href = '<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/Auto_email_schedule_controller/generate_mapimage/' 
      + user + '/' + start_date + '/' + to_date + '/' + location + '/' + group + '/' + region + '/' + manager + '/' + client_id + '/' + schedule_id;
}
```

I need just call the `get_pdfreport();` function in cronjob. It is included in '**distance_reporttest.php**' view file. My server is linux server. Is it possible to run above javascript in cron? If no, please advise me, what can I do?

Comment: What are you running in your cron job? This JS code? Just executing the PHP script? How are you doing that?

Comment: I am including both PHP script and above JS code.

Answer (score 0):

A cronjob just runs a command line script.

You can run a PHP program through the command line using `php /path/to/file.php`, but that output of that script will just be dumped to STDOUT. It won't parse the HTML. It won't extract JavaScript from script elements. It won't execute that JavaScript.

You can run a PHP program by making an HTTP request to a web server supporting PHP. You could do that by running an HTTP client like `curl` or `wget` from the command line. Again, they won't parse the HTML etc etc.

You could do that same thing, but use a tool like Puppeteer which will parse the HTML and run the JS etc etc.

… but that would be a really complicated and expensive way to do it.

---

Rewrite the PHP so the logic currently in JavaScript (which generates some data and then passes it to a different PHP program through the URL) is expressed in PHP instead (and have the PHP program *just use it* instead of passing it to a different PHP program).

Comment: Currently i added the command in cronjob like 'wget -q -O /dev/null http://example.com/foldername/index.php/Autopdf/emailreports' in cpanel. In Emailreports function i am calling above 'distance_report_test_pdf' function.

Comment: @user9456654 — I explained why that doesn't work in the third paragraph of this answer.

Comment: Please exaplain how to add javascript function in php.

Comment: I can't tell you how to rewrite your JavaScript in a different programming language when all you've shown of it is the *least* useful line of code.